# How to pass data from a Node/Express server to the client (JavaScript) while allowing sanitized HTML but preventing XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, express, xss, html-sanitizing

What would be the best way to pass data from a express backend, to the client (JavaScript) so one could render data in the DOM using some sort of client side rendering, while allowing sanitized whitelist HTML and still preventing XSS?

Let's say for example the Node response render method looks like:

```
res.render('index', {
    data : {
        foo: '<a href="myhomepage">foo</p>'
    }
});
```

And for whatever reason it includes unescaped characters. Normally including it in the html/ejs template would be trivial, with something like:

```
<script>
    myVar = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>');
</script>
```

But it chokes on the first double quote of the anchor tag with: `Unexpected token h in JSON at position 18`

We definitely want to allow strings with HTML characters (bold, anchor links, etc...) But want to strip script tags and other such dangerous tags.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Or would one have to traverse all levels of the the data passed to the render method, and run all string keys through some sort of XSS sanitizer engine?

Comment: Not sure why it borks on the JSON-tag, but I would pass the data through DOMPurify before adding it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allow some untrusted html, then it can be sanitized using external libraries. I haven't used it, but DOMPurify mentioned in the comment looks decent. This can be done on either the server or the client before adding the contents of `myVar` to the DOM.

The other problem is transfering the data from the server to the client. This has a separate problem. `JSON.stringify` produces a JavaScript string, but this is parsed twice. Once by the JavaScript engine in the browser, when the script is loaded, and once again by `JSON.parse`. This results in escaped quotes being unescaped before reaching `JSON.parse` and it interpreting them the wrong way.

If `data` is:

```
{ foo: '<a href="myhomepage">foo</p>' }
```

Then `JSON.stringify` would produce:

```
{"foo":"<a href=\"myhomepage\">foo</p>"}
```

This is inserted into the html page to become:

```
myVar = JSON.parse('{"foo":"<a href=\"myhomepage\">foo</p>"}');
```

Here the `\"` sequences are interpreted as quotes by the JavaScript parser so it's the same as:

```
myVar = JSON.parse('{"foo":"<a href="myhomepage">foo</p>"}');
```

The href quotes are now interpreted as close quotes for the property instead of open quotes for the attribute.

You could fix this, but there's another problem with `JSON.parse`. It doesn't account for any surrounding HTML context. Because it's
inside `<script>` tags, then if data is:

```
{ foo: '</script><script>alert(1)</script>' }
```

It will produce the HTML:

```
<script>
    myVar = JSON.parse('{"foo":"</script><script>alert(1)</script>"}');
</script>
```

This contains a valid JavaScript string. It doesn't escape out of the string, but instead escapes directly out of the script tag, and reenters with a new script, resulting in an XSS problem.

Instead, you need something the escapes the both the HTML and JS metacharacters. Something like this should do:

```
myVar = JSON.parse(unescape('<%- escape(JSON.stringify(data)) %>'));
```

Comment: That's what I had anticipated too, but the whole thing chokes on `JSON.parse('{"foo":"<a href=\"myhomepage\">foo</p>"}');` If you just enter that into the console, it errors with `VM5523:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 17` because that's not valid JSON.